# Network Recycle Bin Tool

Tags: networking, recycle-bin

Has any ever used the Network Recycle Bin tool?

Is that legit? Need to have our network shared drives go into a Recycle Bin. A user has deleted a file from one of our network drives and would like to prevent this trouble of recovering the files in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a Linux-based NAS, you might start-off by reading one of the following:

- http://linux.die.net/man/5/smb.conf
- http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/manual4/smbconf.html

The art of recycling, without over-filling your file system, can be a deep and challenging subject.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Good for showing the non-Windows angle. +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice tip on [this page](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/16974-Tip-Network-Recycle-bin) on how to do it with a mapped network drive linked to one of your "My Documents" sub-folders. Worth a try.

> Here's how:
>
> 1. Map a network drive to the network share you want to use. Make sure that
>      the drive is re-connected on logon. If
>      you don't know how to do this, search
>      Google.
> 2. Browse to C:\users\.
> 3. Right-click on one of the folders in this location (I chose saved games)
>      and click properties.
> 4. Select the Location tab.
> 5. Click Move, browse to to root of the drive you mapped in step 1, and
>      click Select Folder.
> 6. Click Ok and click yes in the dialogue box that appears.
> 7. Repeat these same steps for all users on the computer.
>
> You can now verify that the network
>   drive is protected by the recycle bin
>   by right-clicking on the recycle bin
>   and clicking properties. The network
>   drive should be listed in the Recycle
>   Bin Locations column.
>
> Some warnings:
>   1. This only protects files accessed through the mapped network drive, and
>   not by UNC paths. So for example, if
>   you mapped \server\share to z:, and
>   delete something off the z drive, it
>   will go to the recycle bin. However,
>   if you browse to \server\share and
>   delete a file, it will be deleted
>   directly.
>
> 2. I don't know what will happen if your network drive is not available,
>      so beware. This may not work well with
>      laptops.
> 3. What ever files that were supposed to be stored in the folder you select
>      in step 3 will now be stored on your
>      mapped network drive by default. This
>      can actually be quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Network Recycle Bin Tool. It is very useful for us. You can install as a local machine version as a server version on the server side. It will catch deleted network files and copy them to some predefined folder.

[Network Recycle Bin Tool web site](http://networkrecyclebin.info/)