# How do I add additional locations to the Windows 7 Recycle Bin Properties?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, samba, ext4, recycle-bin

I have set up a home network with a small file server running Samba.  I read on a forum post that by re-mapping a user folder on Windows 7 to a network drive, a reference to that drive will be added to the list of Recycle Bin Locations.

The implication of this is that if you delete a file from a network share, regardless of whether it's formatted EXT4 or NTFS, that file is transferred to the Recycle Bin on the desktop rather than permanently deleted.

Does anyone know how to manually edit this list either via the registry or some other config file?

[image: Recycle Bin Properties]

Comment: Related info: [Network Recycle Bin Tool](http://superuser.com/a/263777/23133)